# solidworks - I want to export a plate with bend points

Tags: vba, solidworksapi

```
'**********************
'Copyright(C) 2020 Xarial Pty Limited
'Reference: https://www.codestack.net/solidworks-api/document/sheet-metal/export-dxf-dwg/
'License: https://www.codestack.net/license/
'**********************

Enum SheetMetalOptions_e
    ExportFlatPatternGeometry = 1
    IncludeHiddenEdges = 2
    ExportBendLines = 4
    IncludeSketches = 8
    MergeCoplanarFaces = 16
    ExportLibraryFeatures = 32
    ExportFormingTools = 64
    ExportBoundingBox = 2048
End Enum

Const OUT_PATH As String = "D:\sm.dwg"

Dim swApp As SldWorks.SldWorks

Sub main()

    Set swApp = Application.SldWorks
    
    Dim swPart As SldWorks.PartDoc
    
    Set swPart = swApp.ActiveDoc
    
    Dim modelPath As String
    
    modelPath = swPart.GetPathName
    
    If modelPath = "" Then
        Err.Raise vbError, "", "Part document must be saved"
    End If
    
    If False = swPart.ExportToDWG2(OUT_PATH, modelPath, swExportToDWG_e.swExportToDWG_ExportSheetMetal, True, Empty, False, False, SheetMetalOptions_e.ExportFlatPatternGeometry + SheetMetalOptions_e.ExportBendLines, Empty) Then
        Err.Raise vbError, "", "Failed to export flat pattern"
    End If
    
End Sub
```

solidworks - I want to export a sheet with bend points - unfortunately the above macro does not do it, can someone help me improve it.

The macro exports the plate, but no bend points - where is the error

Answer (score 0):

It was enough to change this line (enter 9) and it started to work

```
If False = swPart.ExportToDWG2(OUT_PATH, modelPath, swExportToDWG_e.swExportToDWG_ExportSheetMetal, True, Empty, False, False, 9 , Empty) Then
        Err.Raise vbError, "", "Failed to export flat pattern"
    End If
```